# Can 'fifo' filter write to the same stream in avconv?

Tags: avconv

I would think that there should be a way to explain to `fifo` filter to write to the same output stream. But when i test that hypothesis with the following:

```
avconv -i 01.webm -filter_complex 'split [s1][s2];[s1] fifo [f];[s2] fifo [f]; [f] copy' -c:v libtheora -an out.mkv
```

I get the error:

```
Output pad "default" for the filter "Parsed filter 1 fifo" of type "fifo" not connected to any destination
```

What i figure is that the second fifo grabs the [f] stream and it no longer is writeable by the first one. But would there be a trick or something to explain to the filter that it is in fact my intention for two filters to dump something into the same place?

P.S. This is not a software choice request. I am trying to figure out how to do this with libav.